# how to use .toggle with jquery 1.9

Tags: toggle, jquery-1.9

i'm trying to use the toggle method with jquery 1.9 but it's been removed and here's a simple example to toggle div content
http://jsfiddle.net/Y5pFe/1/
code :

```
<div class="divone"></div>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.divone').toggle(function() {
$(this).text("click one");
}, function() {
$(this).text("click two");
}); 
});
```

what's the alternative method please ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just use `.click` and assign an attribute as a flag:

```
<div class="divone"></div>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.divone').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        $(this).text("removing click");
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    } else {
        $(this).text("adding click");
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var flag=0;
$('div.divone').on('click', function(){

    var menu = $(this);

     if(flag==0)
       {

            menu.text("click one");

            flag=1;
            return;
        }

        if(flag==1)
        {

            menu.text("click two");

            flag=0;
            return;
         }





    });
});
```