# Toggle Jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I don't know where is the problem, but the toggle doesn't work :

**[MY JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ag4he0qb/)**

```
$("#header").toggle(
    function(){$("#header").css({"background-color": "pink"});},
    function(){$("#header").css({"background-color": "blue"});},
    function(){$("#header").css({"background-color": "green"});
});
```

Comment: Did you check console for any errors?

Comment: This method has been removed from jq 1.9  https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @A. Wolff : you're right. What is the alternative ?

Comment: Finally, i use Jquery 1.7...

Comment: Best alternative is to use click event

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900838/how-to-use-toggle-with-jquery-1-9

Comment: please review the docs for .toggle(): http://api.jquery.com/toggle/. I seriously think you are trying to do something else.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Check out this fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06e8w2ad/)

Used this in javascript:

```
var colors = ["pink", "blue", "green"];
var index = 0;
$("#header").click(function() {

  index++;
  if(index > colors.length - 1)
     index = 0;
  $("#header").css({
    "background-color": colors[index]
  });

});
```